# Mvvm. Label never updated. (in countdown)

Tags: vb.net, xaml, mvvm

I must create a countdown, but the label doesn't change color, and content.

This is the XAML................................................

```
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Msg, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           Background="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="200,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

This is my class.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System


Public Class abc
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

Protected Sub OnNotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Private Property _Msg As String
Private Property _Color As String

Public Property Msg As String
    Get
        Return _Msg
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Msg = value
        OnPropertyChanged("Msg")
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Msg")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Color As String
    Get
        Return _Color
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Color = value
        OnPropertyChanged("Color")
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Color")
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()

    For i = 10 To 0 Step -1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Select Case i
            Case 11, 10, 9, 8
                Msg = "Wait" + i.ToString
                Color = "Green"
            Case 7, 6, 5, 4
                Msg = "Start" + i.ToString
                Color = "Yellow"
            Case Is < 3
                Msg = "End" + i.ToString
                Color = "Red"
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Because the label is not updated ? ( see Sub Nnew() )
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Where do you set your DataContext?

Comment: DataContest is in windows.xaml.vb   (sub new())

Comment: Can you post this xaml too? Does any binding of your view work?

Comment: Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As    RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim x As New abc
        Me.DataContext = x
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You're sleeping the UI thread during the countdown, so it can't update the bindings. You need to either do this in a separate thread or use a DispatcherTimer for the countdown.

Also while you're at it remove the TwoWay mode from the Label binding, how can a label update a value?

Comment: Also while you're at it remove the TwoWay mode from the Label binding, how can a label update a value? **I try all solutions**. So, for this problem I must create a **thread** ?

Comment: Yes, you need to either do the work in a separate a thread or use a DispatcherTimer to trigger the updates. It's also possible to use [asynchronous programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx). Regarding the label binding, a label can't change the value it's bound to, so it should be OneWay instead of TwoWay.